# Add ShowSaveButton in Directions widget arcgis api 3.38

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, widget

I am working with Directions Widget with arcgis JS version 3.38
and want to display the Save button on the widget, so I have added the ShowSavsButton parameter.
But still can't displayed on the widget!

```
 var directionsW = new Directions({
            map: map,
            routeTaskUrl:                   
             "https://192.168.7.45:6443/arcgis/rest/services/CALCUL_ITINERAIRE/NAServer/Route",
            **showSaveButton: true**
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It doesn't even work in their [sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=widget_directions_basic)

Comment: It works you need just to uncomment the following parameters  "showSaveButton: true"

Comment: My mistake...I had uncommented it but didn't provide a route. I was expecting the button to appear before entering an origin/destination

Comment: do you have any idea why I cannot see it even if I enter an Origin/Destiniation

Comment: Is that "Network Analyst Server federated with ArcGIS Online or Portal? 
If not, it will not know where to save the route, so doesn't display the button.
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/directions-amd.html#showsavebutton